# How to change the default behavior of my sites?

Tags: my-site

I have configured my site on Sharepoint 2013 and my sites are getting provisioned correctly. But, I am wondering if there is anyway to provision my sites with a different look and with some apps/webparts other than the ones that come with it by default?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Ramakrishna

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a SharePoint solution in which you make [feature stapling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861862%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

You can find plenty of info about feature stapling for all versions of SharePoint on [Google](https://www.google.dk/search?q=sharepoint%202013%20feature%20stapling&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb#client=firefox-a&hs=81F&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=fflb&sclient=psy-ab&q=sharepoint%202013%20feature%20stapling%20mysite&oq=sharepoint%202013%20feature%20stapling%20mysite&gs_l=serp.3..33i21.5590.6262.0.6393.7.7.0.0.0.0.324.1258.0j3j2j1.6.0.ekwqrh..0.0...1.1.11.psy-ab.7aEUq2MW_BE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45580626,d.Yms&fp=7ed5ac70b8bb7557&biw=1920&bih=1081) and [Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=sharepoint%202013%20feature%20stapling%20mysite&go=&qs=ds&form=QBLH&filt=all).